# Reactjs, Net and authenication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, reactjs

Got a great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356666/net-web-4-5-1-routing-anything-not-authenticated) to another post about routing in Net Web...

Basically, I wanted everything that isn't authenticated to get sent to a static file and went authenticated to another static file.  Each static file has a specific Reactjs set of components.  The non-authentication page is just a splash page while authenticated users come into the SPA application.

What I didn't think about was how to deal with physical versus relative path.  My static files are under a folder called **Statics** and made relative paths to styles/javascript.  However, the virtual directory defined in IIS isn't carried over into these relative paths.  Not sure if I can MapPageRoute (working with Web API not MVC) specific css and javascript files?

And another problem is that I am using token (OAuth) authentication.  No idea how on the initial contact with the server to send along the token to the constraint in the Routing table (per @Brain Deragon suggestion)?  Only thing I can come up with an have a dummy index page that just picks up the token (from sessionStorage) and sends that along.

Would love some advice from people that setup up token authentication with Web Net and have a "disconnected" client (i.e. Reactjs/Angular) not part of any MVC back-end solution as to how they solve identification plus mapping.

Comment: Ran across this [blog](http://enome.github.io/javascript/2014/05/09/lets-create-our-own-router-component-with-react-js.html) which uses [Page.js](http://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/) to do routing "of rendered" components locally with React.  This will likely solve my problems since I remove all routing from Dot Net and let Reactjs (with Page.js) determine what to show based of a token validated against a server side control.

Comment: Just wanted to post back that routing in the client is the way to go.  Page.js was fairly easy to use leaving Web API protection only on the controllers.